# How can i pass data from child component to parent component which in above second level by using function base in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a  project structure like below

```
- components
    - layout
       - layoutA
          - header.js
          - footer.js
          - layout.js
- views
    - blogsite
       - catgoriesView.js
- App.js
```

in header.js i have props.sections for pass list of menu

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        
        <Toolbar component="nav" variant="dense" className={classes.toolbarSecondary}>
            {sections.map((section) => (
                <NavLink
                    key={section.title}
                    to={section.url}
                    className={classes.toolbarLink}
                >
                    {section.title}
                </NavLink>
            ))}
        </Toolbar>
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

in the layout.js is compose header,footer and children

```
const Layout = (props) => {

   return (
       <>
        <Container maxWidth="lg" >
            <BlogHeader title={props.title} sections={props.sections} ></BlogHeader>
            {props.children}
            <BlogFooter></BlogFooter>
        </Container>
       </>
   )
```

}

in App.js have a main component

```
const BlogSite = () => {
    
      const title = "Demo"
    
      const sections = [
        { title: 'React js', url: '/category/reactjs' },
        { title: 'React Native', url: '/category/reactnative' },
      ];
        return <>
            <Layout title={title} sections={sections} >
              <BrowserRouter>
                <Route path="/category/:category" component={CategoriesView}></Route>
                ...
                ...
              </BrowserRouter >
            </Layout>
          </>
        }
```

in categoriesView.js to render view

```
const View = (props) => {
    const { category } = useParams()

    return (
        <Panel title={category} abstract="Id Lorem ipsum .....et."></Panel>

    )
}
```

try my code >> https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-pass-data-from-child-component-to-parent-component-which-in-above-seco-forked-gp04r?file=/src/App.js

I have a problem categoriesView component not rerender when clicked NavLink.
so i tried useEffect in categoriesView is not working. how i can to solve this or expert have a bestest this way please guide me.

Comment: I copy/pasted as much of your code snippet [here in a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-pass-data-from-child-component-to-parent-component-which-in-above-seco-wt8l3) and `View` appears to rerender with updated route match params. Is `Panel` not rerendering? Can you try to provide a bit more detail or provide your own *running* codesandbox that reproduces your issue?

Comment: @DrewReese this code >> https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-pass-data-from-child-component-to-parent-component-which-in-above-seco-forked-gp04r?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are rendering more than one `Router`. The links are in the routing context of the ***outer*** `Router` while the routes themselves are rendered into the context of the ***inner*** `Router`. When a link is clicked the outer router context is handling the URL update to the address bar, but the inner router context isn't aware of the change so it doesn't update the `Route`s it is rendering.

```
<BrowserRouter> // <-- Outer Router
  <div className="App">
    <Layout title={title} sections={submenusections}>
      <BrowserRouter> // <-- Inner Router
        <Route path="/category/:category" component={Category}></Route>
        <Route path="/blog" component={() => <h1>Blog ..</h1>}></Route>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Layout>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

## Solution

You need only one `Router` wrapping your app to provide a routing context. Remove the inner `Router`.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="App">
    <Layout title={title} sections={submenusections}>
      <Route path="/category/:category" component={Category} />
      <Route path="/blog" component={() => <h1>Blog ..</h1>} />
    </Layout>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-can-i-pass-data-from-child-component-to-parent-component-which-in-above-seco]